# Apache Storm: Assigning executors to slots

Tags: apache-storm

I am exploring Apache Storm. I know that there is no way of determining what tasks get mapped to which node. I wanted to know if there is any way to even guess which executors are grouped together. For instance, consider a linear chain topology with 1 spout and 2 bolts:

Spout -> Bolt1 -> Bolt2

If there is a 3 node cluster, and numworkers = 3, with combined parallelism = 9 (3 spouts + 2 x 3 bolts), is there any way of determining how executors are grouped? I have read that the default scheduler distributes the load evenly in a round robin manner. Does it mean that all the workers will have one instance each of: 
S -> B1 -> B2 executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the default scheduler, you are right. If you have 3 workers, each worker will get assigned one instance of your Spout, Bolt1, and Bolt2.

The order in which the default scheduler assigns executors to workers, is round robin as you stated correctly. In more detail, the round robin assignment for each logical operator happens for all its executors before the scheduler considers the next logical operator. However, the order of the logical operators themselves is not fixed. See the code here for more details: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/0.9.x-branch/storm-core/src/clj/backtype/storm/scheduler

If you want to influence this behavior, you can provide a custom scheduler. See an example here: https://xumingming.sinaapp.com/885/twitter-storm-how-to-develop-a-pluggable-scheduler/

Comment: I guess then in case of different parallelism hints, in our case, 1 Spout , 4 Bolt1, 4 Bolt2, it would be: S -> B1 -> B2, B1 B1 -> B2 , B1 -> B2 B2. in this case, or the first case mentioned with uniform distribution, does the stream grouping consider all the instances of a component? Say shuffle grouping for B1 considers all the bolt instances, even if they are on different physical machines, right?

Comment: Yes. This assignments sounds about right. And yes, groupings like shuffle or fieldsGrouping do consider all executors. One exception is localOfShuffle that prefers local consumers over remote consumers.